# ng-file-upload: Upload file from mobile Firefox browser

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, firefox, ng-file-upload

I use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) with AngularJS in my web app and it works great in PC browsers. However, when I open the app in Android Firefox, I am not able to upload files. But it works with Chrome. Nothing comes up when I click the file select button.

Is there anyway to make file upload does not work with FIrefox?

Thank you.

Comment: I also use ng-file-upload, and my android 4.4.2, latest firefox, it works well.

Comment: Though fileupload is not  well support in the webview.

Comment: One remote possibility ... In general, file upload would not work as expected if your surrounding `<form>` tag does not have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.